# DNS Transfer from Plesk Domain Controller to Azure

Tags: azure, dns

Good Afternoon,

after 2-3 Days trying to move my Domain from a Webhoster to Azure, i need your Help.

My actual Webhoster has Plesk. Over Plesk i can access and change all the DNS Entrys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns

Based on this Walkthrough i'll have created 4 Entrys at my actual WebHoster and the Verification of the Domain is allright. When i run the command
`nslookup -type=SOA #mydomain#` i see a azure dns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain

After that i wanted to create a Test App in Azure. Based on the above Walkthroughs i managed to set my Custom Domain for my App Service. I made this Settings at my old WebHoster and in my newly created DNS-Zone in Azure.

So far so good. So I have deactivated the local DNS Service in Plesk in order to move on to Azure that should manage my DNS now. So i'll have deleted the Custom Domain in my App Service and created it again but this time it should point to my Azure DNS. But in the Creation Dialog of Creating a Custom Domain it tells me that im not the owner of the Domain.

Im confused and floating somwhere in the Dark. Could some guys point to the right direction. Do i have to do additional Entrys in the Azure DNS?

I hope someone can understand my bad Descriptions :).

Thanks for every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you [host your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns), you **only need** to manage your DNS entry in the Azure DNS zone.

Thus, in the step of [migrating an active DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain), you can create domain verification records in the Azure DNS zone.

[image]

Then you also need to add the custom domain to the web app and remap the active DNS records via `A` or `CNAME` record following that steps in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nancy for the answer.

i could solve the Problem. I found this ?-Button in Plesk that let you test the DNS-Zone on the Nameserver. There was an ip poping up that does not belong to an A-Reccord. But the weird thing is thtat this Ip-Adress also did not belong to the App-Service IP.

But as soon as i added this Ip everything went fine and is working now.

Thanks